# Read files from remote EC2 instance with Javascript?

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2

I have files stored in my remote EC2 server. When users pull up my website, I need to be able to get the text from those files in real time and pull them into the website. Like Github does.

How do I go about doing this?

If this doesn't make sense, I want to do what Github is doing. You can navigate between files on a website that are stored on a server, and you just read from the server and get that data to render to the user. I am using firebase for hosting, but changing to an S3 is possible if absolutely necessary. Thank you.

Comment: S3 and CloudFront for caching the files, while EC2 provides only dynamic content, would be my recommendation.

Comment: @Marcin I see, thanks a ton!

Comment: @Marcin In this case, would an S3 work for Github? From what I can see, S3 just stores files. I need all my users to be able to push to their own branches, is that possible with S3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 has versioning but its not a full on Source Control Management tool, so it doesn't natively support branching or merging. Usually for a database file system I'd recommend using a Virtual Path Provider technology where you read documents out of a database, eg HTML files used in a CMS.

Github essentially is a web interface for GIT. The whole thing is run using a plethora of GIT SCM repo's.

Hence what you want is **AWS CodeCommit**, a fully-managed source control service that hosts secure Git-based repositories.

Edit:

> I need all my users to be able to push to their own branches.

If you don't need merging you could simply use an S3 bucket by creating folders (programmatically) for each user. With a Policy you can restrict each user to their own bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": [
                {
                    "AWS": [
                        "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/ROLENAME",
                        "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:user/**${aws:username}**"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket"
        }
```

Ref: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, i've got a question. How would I read from CodeCommit? I see that I can obviously manually pull, but if I want to have a website read files as the user navigates the file system like Github, that is possible correct? I can't seem to find it anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Scroll down and see all the GIT related CLI commands: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/cmd-ref.html

Comment: I apologize if i'm misunderstanding, but I understand this can be done with CLI. What I don't see is how to read files from codecommit with Javascript in the browser

Comment: Good point, in AWS you can do everything from the CLI - it's a good reference for everything. Using a programming language you want to use the AWS SDK for that language. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CodeCommit.html

Comment: If the whole thing is running off JavaScript and CodeCommit you could very cheaply host it in S3